# Find the start and end position of a word in a string based on the index position of that word from a label list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a sentence

```
str = 'cold weather gives me cold'
```

and a list

```
 tag = ['O','O','O','O','disease']
```

This indicates that 5th word in the sentence is a disease type. Now I need to get the starting and ending position of the 5th word.

If I just do string search with 'cold' it will give me the starting position of the "cold" which occurs first.

Comment: So you basically need the 5th word of the String? Or do you need its indices?

Comment: Do you want first and last word of COLD?

Comment: I only want the last COLD, the 5th word of the string's indices.

Comment: looks like you just need `str.split()[4]`

Comment: btw, ok, it’s just an example here, but ‘str’ variable name will hide the corresponding builtin.

Comment: what are your constraints on what separates words in the original and how have you parsed to get the indices?   mystring.split()?  something else? always 1 space?  no other characters?

Comment: @JLPeyret yes you are correct. I just put up an example very quickly. actual variable names are different in my program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
def get(str,target_index):
  start = len(" ".join(str.split(" ")[:target_index])) + 1
  end = start + len(str.replace('.','').split(' ')[target_index])
  return (start,end)

str = 'cold weather gives me cold.' 
tag = ['O','O','O','O','disease']
start,end = get(str,tag.index('disease'))
print(start,end,str[start:end]) # outputs 22 26 cold

str = 'cold weather gives me cold'
tag = ['O','O','O','O','disease']
start,end = get(str,tag.index('disease'))
print(start,end,str[start:end]) # outputs 22 26 cold

str = 'cold weather gives me cold and cough' 
tag = ['O','O','O','O','disease']
start,end = get(str,tag.index('disease'))
print(start,end,str[start:end]) # outputs 22 26 cold
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/GrowingKeyDemoware).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

First find the disease index from tag then disease name from data then find start and end index:

```
strData = 'cold weather gives me cold' 
tag = ['O','O','O','O','disease']
diseaseIndex = tag.index('disease')
diseaseName = strData.split()[diseaseIndex]
print(diseaseName)
diseaseNameStartIndex = sum(len(word) for (index, word) in enumerate(strData.split()) if index< diseaseIndex ) + diseaseIndex
diseaseNameEndIndex = diseaseNameStartIndex + len(diseaseName) -1
print("diseaseNameStartIndex = ",diseaseNameStartIndex)
print("diseaseNameEndIndex = ",diseaseNameEndIndex)
```

output:

```
cold
diseaseNameStartIndex =  22
diseaseNameEndIndex =  25
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will output the start and end position of a given word, assuming words are separated by spaces:

```
str = 'cold weather gives me cold'
word_idx = 4 # index of the word we are looking for

split_str = str.split(' ')
print(split_str[word_idx]) # outputs 'cold'

start_pos = 0
for i in range(word_idx):
    start_pos += len(split_str[i]) + 1 # add one because of the spaces between words
end_pos = start_pos + len(split_str[word_idx]) - 1

print(start_pos) # prints 22
print(end_pos) # prints 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply split the string and then join it again, but this is somewhat awkward.

```
string_list = string.split(" ")
word_start = len(" ".join(string_list[:4])) + 1
word_end = word_start + len(string_list[4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools` and `re`:

```
import re
from itertools import accumulate

def find_index(string, n):
    words = string.split()
    len_word = len(words[n])
    end_index = list(accumulate(map(len, re.split('(\s)' , string))))[::2][n]
    return end_index - len_word, end_index - 1
```

Using it:

```
find_index('cold weather gives me cold', 4) #5th word means 4 in indexing
```

Output:

```
(22, 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function:

```
def find_index(s, n):
    length = len(s.split()[n])
    index = [(0, len(s.split()[0]) - 1)]
    for i in s.split():
        index.append((index[-1][0] + len(i), index[-1][1] + len(i)))
    return index[n + 1]
print(find_index('cold weather gives me cold', 4))
```

Output:

```
(22, 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do this for a long line, it is better to use an `iterator`, which would generate the word starting and ending position using `re.finditer` method, and then find the nth element of the iterator using `islice`

```
>>> str = 'cold weather gives me cold' 
>>> word_pos = iter((match.group(), match.span(1)) for match in re.finditer(r'(\S+)\S', string))
>>>
>>> n=4
>>> next(islice(word_pos, n, n+1))
('cold', (22, 25))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` with a list comprehension:

```
import re
s = 'cold weather gives me cold' 
new_s = re.findall('\w+|\s+', s)
l = [(a, sum(map(len, new_s[:i]))) for i, a in enumerate(new_s) if a != ' ']
```

---

```
tag = ['O','O','O','O','disease'] 
result = [[c if not c else c, c+len(d)] for a, [d, c] in zip(tag, l) if a == 'disease']
```

Output:

```
[[22, 26]]
```